# Lower model evaluation metrics than training metrics for same data used in training

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, evaluation

I have trained a LSTM model using some data. When I evaluate the performance of the trained model using the same data as used during training, I get different results. The metrics I am using for evaluation are accuracy, precision, recall, and F1 score. I have used PyTorch.

My testing code `test_model.py`:

```
import numpy as np
import json
from train_utils import *
from dataset_utils import *
from models import *
from metrics import *

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.utils.tensorboard as tb
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

def test(encoded_seq, y_label, model_path, model_class, config):
   
    device = torch.device('cuda:6' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

    testset = SequenceDataset(encoded_seq, y_label)  
    test_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=len(testset))

    checkpoint = torch.load(model_path, map_location=torch.device(device))

    args = {'n_nts': config['MODEL']['embedding_dim'], 'n_bins': encoded_seq.shape[1],
                'bin_rnn_size': config['MODEL']['hidden_dim'], 'num_layers': config['MODEL']['hidden_layers'],
                'dropout': config['TRAINER']['dropout'], 'bidirectional': config['MODEL']['bidirectional']}
    model = att_DNA(args, 2)

    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
    model.to(device)

    loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    data, labels = iter(test_dataloader).next()

    model.eval()
    raw_out = model.forward(data.to(device))[0]
    loss = loss_fn(raw_out, labels.long().to(device))
    print("Loss: ", loss)

    m = Metrics()  # m.metrics initialised to {0,0,0}
    metrics, predictions = m.get_metrics(raw_out.detach().clone().cpu(), labels)
    #print('True labels', labels)
    #print('Predicted labels', predictions)
    print('Metrics: ', metrics)
    model = None  # Clear model
```

The metrics are calculated in `metrics.py` as:

```
class Metrics():
    def __init__(self):
        self.metrics = {'prec': 0, 'recall': 0, 'f1': 0, 'acc': 0}
    
    def pred_from_raw(raw):
        pred = torch.argmax(torch.softmax(raw, dim=1), dim=1).cpu().numpy()
        return pred

    def metrics_classification(raw, y_true, avg):
        f1 = metrics.f1_score(pred, y_true.numpy(), average=avg, zero_division=0)
        prec = metrics.precision_score(pred, y_true.numpy(), average=avg, zero_division=0)
        rec = metrics.recall_score(pred, y_true.numpy(), average=avg, zero_division=0)
        return f1, prec, rec
    
    def get_metrics(self, raw, y_true, avg=None):
        print("Calculating metrics")

        f1, prec, recall = metrics_classification(raw, y_true, avg)
        pred = pred_from_raw(raw)
        acc = metrics.accuracy_score(pred, y_true.numpy())
        self.metrics = {'prec': prec, 'recall': recall, 'f1': f1, 'acc': acc}
        return self.metrics, pred
```

The data is loaded as:

```
class SequenceDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data, labels):
        self.data = torch.from_numpy(data).float()
        self.labels = torch.tensor(labels).float()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # Return data (seq_len, batch, input_dim), label for index
        return (self.data[idx], self.labels[idx])
```

My training metrics look like:

```
Epoch: 4 ------ TRAIN ------
train loss: 0.5386, {'prec': 0.7369, 'recall': 0.7262, 'f1': 0.7002, 'acc': 0.7664}
Epoch: 4 ------ VAL ------
val loss: 0.5143, {'prec': 0.7692, 'recall': 0.7653, 'f1': 0.7386, 'acc': 0.7942}
```

while my test metrics (on the training data) using the trained model (through the script `test_model.py` are:

```
Metrics:  {'prec': array([0.5017, 0.4878]), 'recall': array([0.4949, 0.4946]), 
'f1': array([0.4983, 0.4912]), 'acc': 0.4948}
```

Why is there a discrepancy in the metrics even thought the training and evaluation is done on the same data?

Answer (score 0):

could you share your full source code or you can further check your train, val, and test data while calling `def test(encoded_seq, y_label, model_path, model_class, config)`fucntion.